# Display Hierarchical Data in TreeView

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I am simply trying to display hierarchical Data in a TreeView, but I just can't figure out how to make it display more than the First two Levels. (And i have read almost evry TreeView post, maybe the problem is my (miss)understatement of the Bindings in this case)

I have simplyfied my Datastructure for this test:

```
public class Node
{
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }

    public Node Parent { get; set; }

    public string Expression { get; set; }
}
```

Xaml currently looks like this: (Please notice that I have changed it several times now, but this here is the original state i have come up with: )

```
<Window x:Class="Klammern_Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Klammern_Test"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="439" Width="402">
    <Window.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}">
            <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" Header="{Binding Expression}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Root}" Margin="12,41,12,12" Name="treeView" />            
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is how I am trying to Populate my Treeview:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
        public Node Root { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Parser = new StringParser();
            Root = Parser.Parse(Tbx_Eingabe.Text);       
            treeView.Items.Add(PopulateTreeView(Root));



        }

        private TreeViewItem PopulateTreeView(Node node)
        {
            TreeViewItem treeViewItem = new TreeViewItem();
            treeViewItem.IsExpanded = true;
            treeViewItem.Header = node.Expression;


            foreach (Node child in node.Children)
            {
                treeViewItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = child.Expression });

                if (child.Children.Count > 0)
                {
                    PopulateTreeView(child);
                }
            }

            return treeViewItem;
        }
}
```

What am I missing?

### EDIT:

After trying around with almulo's hints, I found this with the Snoop-tool, but I can't tell what it means at all, I have found no other red line and no entry to the Binding Errors column at all.

[image: Snoop screenshot of potential binding Error]

Comment: What does `Parser.Parse()` return? What's the type of `Root`?

Comment: It returns a `Node`, `Root` is also a `Node`

Comment: Mmmh, that may be the problem... `ItemsSource` is expecting a collection, and `Root` is a single `Node`. I'll edit my answer below.

Comment: Oh, so maybe it will work when I just change Root to a List<Node>?

Comment: @almulo I cant belive it, but it really works!! Thanks a LOT for your efford!

Comment: Glad to read that :) You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `TreeViewItem` inside a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` which is what your TreeView's TreeViewItems will use to create themselves is... confusing.

Inside your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` you should just add the controls you want the item "header" to have. In this case, I guess it should be a `TextBlock` since you just wanna show some text.

Then use the `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemSource` property to bind the children of your node.

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Expression}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Also, in you code-behind, you shouldn't manipulate the `TreeView.Items` or the `TreeViewItem.Items` directly, since you are already using Bindings and the `ItemsSource` properties.

Instead, remove the `PopulateTreeView` method and let your `Root` property work as items source for the TreeView. But in order for this to work, you'll have to notify the view when the `Root` property changes its value.

To do so, implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and fire the `PropertyChanged` event every time `Root` changes.

**EDIT:** The ItemsControl property `ItemsSource` expects a collection (more specifically, an `IEnumerable`), so `Root` needs to be one. Even if it has a single item, like this:

```
public class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // ...

    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Parser = new StringParser();
        Root = new Node[] { Parser.Parse(Tbx_Eingabe.Text) };

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Root"));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: That doesnt works for me either, I still only get the two levels of items, but I Have anoter clue now, maybe its the fault of my Population Method who overwrites the contents made by bindings? I have tried to remove that but that just results in my TreeView displaying nothing.

Comment: Well, you certainly are overriding your bindings. Didn't realize you were accesing the TreeView's `Items` property directly... Actually, that should probably throw an exception, since you're not supposed to be able to use `ItemsSource` and `Items` at the same time.

Comment: I'll extend my answer to suggest some changes to your code-behind.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but it sadly still does not work. I have debugged it and found out that the PropertyChanged event is not fired because of PopertyChanged being Null all time, do i have to register it manually somewhere? 
Also is it correct to assign the Datacontext of the mainwindow to its codebehind at the beginning?

Comment: somehow  PropertyChanged is not Null anymore (maybe because i also implemented the interface in the Node class itself?) and the event gets fired, but still there is nothing happening in my Window

Comment: That's weird, I just copied your code and it worked right away... I only had to create my own "parser", which just created a list of Nodes up to three levels deep. I guess your parser returns a correct list, too, so I'm not sure what could be wrong...

Comment: As for using `DataContext = this`, it is generally ill-advised to do it that way. But in a self-contained view that's not gona be reused, it could be ok.

Comment: Use Snoop or check VS's Output tab to look for Binding errors. It may be that your bindings are not working correctly, and reading the actual error message could shed more light over the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I have tried looking up the VS's Output but there was nothing special about it to me. But with snoop I have found something interesting I guess.. I dont really understand what its saying but it looks like an error of some sort, I'll update my question..